# How to get text of a display:none element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenide

I have div class which has id with display:none.I need to get the text out of the id.

I have tried by using javascript executor. but I am not getting the text value from the ID.

```
SelenideElement element = $$("[class*=abc]");
JavaScriptExecutor js = (JavaScriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element);
```

Here is the HTML code. test-id of text is hidden.

```
< div class = "abc 1frr">
 <div class = "efg-ghj">
<div class = "kjs-w4ejd">
 <div class = "dfdfdf_fjjks"></div>
<div class ="_s8js3244" test-id="aaa-bbb">Hello</div>
</div>
</div>
< div class = "abc 1frr">
 <div class = "efg-ghj">
<div class = "kjs-w4ejd">
 <div class = "dfdfdf_fjjks"></div>
<div class ="_s8js3244" test-id="aaa-bbb">How</div>
</div>
</div>
< div class = "abc 1frr">
 <div class = "efg-ghj">
<div class = "kjs-w4ejd">
 <div class = "dfdfdf_fjjks"></div>
<div class ="_s8js3244" test-id="aaa-bbb">are</div>
</div>
</div>
< div class = "abc 1frr">
 <div class = "efg-ghj">
<div class = "kjs-w4ejd">
 <div class = "dfdfdf_fjjks"></div>
<div class ="_s8js3244" test-id="aaa-bbb">You</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am expecting output as to get Hello,How,are,You.Due to element hidden I see all other values except this test-id text value.

I would appreciate of anyone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a text form the attribute, please refer narrow your search criteria with Selenide. Right now I see you are passing Selenide elements collection($$). When you try to find by id (as mentioned above), you also are giving a collection. If you want to get a whole text (your expectations), refer to a higher div class/id and use `$(higher_div_element).getText()` or `String neededText = $("[class='abc 1frr']").parent().getText();`
Tip: Try not to mix Selenide with JS when there are lots of other options. There is always a possibility to get element text or value with selenide. 
To give you more advice, please send a bigger snap of the HTML code (few attributes upper)

If you really want to use selenide collections (which I don't suggest you to get a text), you can simply write something like that:
`int elementSize = $$("[test-id='aaa-bbb'").size();` - you get 4
now simply make a for loop and pass the variable to:

```
$$("[test-id='aaa-bbb'").get(i).getText();
```